# Order of elements in a List when serialized over the wire

Tags: java

I have this class

```java
public interface EntityCondition extends Serializable {
  enum BINARY_OP {
    INTERSECT, MINUS, UNION, CONCAT
  }
  @Nullable
  @Value.Default
  default BINARY_OP binaryOperator() {
    return BINARY_OP.INTERSECT;
  }
}
```

A *chainable* list of conditions. It is sent over the wire through Java RMI both as List object and serialized object using [MsgPack](https://github.com/msgpack/msgpack-java):

```java
MessagePack msgpack = new MessagePack();
byte[] serializedConditions = msgPack.write(conditions);
```

```java
/* Remote methods */
void setCondtions(List<EntityCondition> conditions) throws RemoteException;
void setCondtions(byte[] serializedConditions) throws RemoteException;
```

How do you make sure that when List is serialized over RMI and MsgPack that it will maintain the order of elements?

Comment: One way is to sort the List after deserializing based on a property which guarantees the order before serializing. I'm not sure this is possible in your case.

Comment: My immediate question is...Why would you expect that it wouldn't?  A list, after all, is an ordered data structure.  I would think that any serialization that didn't preserve a List's order would be considered broken.

Answer (score 2):

It is an unwritten assumption that serialization of an object followed by deserialization will (unless *specified* otherwise) produce a copy of the original object.  Since the state of a `List` includes the exact order of its elements,  it is reasonable to assume serialization followed by deserialization will preserve element order.

However, this is not explicitly stated in the javadocs for `List` or the standard list implementations<sup>1</sup>.  And even if it was specified in the `List` API that a serializable `List` *must* preserve the order of its elements, we need to consider the possibility of an implementation that ignores this.

At least in theory.

In practice, AFAIK all Java SE standard `List` classes that support serialization *do* preserve element order ... as expected.

And if you need to confirm this, you can do this by examining the classes implementations of `readObject` and `writeObject` to see what they actually do.

For objects that serialized using the default serialization mechanism, the `ObjectInputStream` and `ObjectOutputStream` classes implement the Object Serialization protocol spec, which is guaranteed to provide an accurate copy of the original.

<sup>1 - If it is stated somewhere in the javadocs, I couldn't find it!</sup>

---

The above assumes that standard Java object serialization is used.

For a 3rd-party serializer library like `MessagePack`, you would need to look at the guarantees that it provides and / or examine its implementation to be absolutely sure.

However, if such a library *didn't* preserve `List` element order, most people would regard it as a fundamental flaw, and probably a "show stopper".

Comment: To be clear: The documentation for "[java.util.List](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html#iterator--)" states that `List`s are _ordered_ collections, and that most of its methods iterate their contents "in proper sequence (from first to last element)".  Your answer suggests that that is not a strong enough guarantee that implementations must preserve the item order of a List.

Comment: @PeterO.  No.  That's not what I am saying.  What I am saying is that there is no guarantee that all list implementations (including custom and 3rd-party implementations) will **correctly** implement the behavior specified and / or implied by the API.  (BTW, the text you found doesn't explicitly state that serialization preserves order.  Like I said, it isn't stated explicitly.  It is only implied.)